# Async await and fetch always returning error

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I am fetching data with fetch and I always get this error:

```
  async fetchPhotos(token, placeid) {
    const _PLACEID = placeid ? placeid : this.props.attributes.placeid;
    const _TOKEN = token ? token : this.props.attributes.token;

    if (!_TOKEN || !_PLACEID) {
      return false;
    }

    const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=${_TOKEN}&placeid=${_PLACEID}`;
    console.log(url);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('you got an error bro: ' + error.toString());

      this.setState({
        apiResponseCode: '400',
        apiErrorMessage: error.toString(),
        loading: false,
      });
    }
  }
```

However if I manually plug the url into my browser it works fine, so I dont know why it keeps erroring?

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: Did you bind your function within the constructor to access this.props?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the error was CORS related. I needed to run my fetch request through a proxy server.

So rather than calling google directly I call a sever like this:

```
const url = 'http://myproxyserver.test/wp-json/google-places/v1/get-reviews';
```